# Marionette - Help to understand how the components work

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm developing a fairly big SPA and I have decided to use Backbone for this. My app is doing pretty well, with routers, page sections, templates, a login system and CRUD areas. And there is 2 different areas, where some users can access both or only one. Everything is modularized with RequireJS' help. But many things I'm having to write on my own and I started to think if there is a better way to do it.

I rode a lot about Marionette and I became very fond of how it handles some issues and tasks, like zombie views and attach regions to a layout... only to mention some. But it's being difficult to  find out how the components work or what they are supposed to do. 
It would be nice to have some directions.

I made a mind map, so it's gonna be easier (for some) to understand my question:

[image]

Things I understood (please, correct me if I'm missing something):

- An ItemView is a small portion of an element, like a Header's navigation or a Header's search form
- A Layout is a collection of ItemViews: The whole "Header".
- A Region is attached to the application itself and needs a layout instance to a region's param; But it can have directly a ItemView related to it.
- The AppRouter is attached to the application.

And things I don't understant quite well:

- Where in this structure is located a composite view?
- What can I do with a Controller? What exactly it is supposed to do? Is it directly related to the Application? Can I attach the AppRouter to it?

Any help would be awesome. Thanks in adv.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "What can I to a controller"?

Comment: @net.uk.sweet Sry, I meant: "What can I do with a Controller? What it exactly does?". I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

*An ItemView is a small portion of an element, like a Header's navigation or a Header's search form*

I think the description in the [documentation](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md) is better, but essentially `ItemView` is your base view type in Marionette.

> An ItemView is a view that represents a single item. That item may be
>   a Backbone.Model or may be a Backbone.Collection. Whichever it is
>   though, it will be treated as a single item.

*A Layout is a collection of ItemViews: The whole "Header".*

A `Layout` is a combination of an `ItemView` and a collection of `Regions`. You can use it to organise views of various types, `ItemView`, `CollectionView`, `CompositeView`, another `Layout`, into a specific layout. (Again, see [documentation](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md)).

*Where in this structure is located a composite view?*

`CompositeView` is interchangeable with `ItemView` in your diagram, see also `CollectionView`. In simple terms, an `ItemView` is generally the visual represention of a model, a `CollectionView` represents a collection of `ItemViews`, and a `CompositeView` is a combination of both.

*What can I do with a Controller? What exactly it is supposed to do? Is it directly related to the Application? Can I attach the AppRouter to it?*

Again, referring to the [documentation](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.controller.md):

> This is a very generic, multi-purpose object that can serve many
>   different roles, in many different scenarios.

Which, I'll admit, doesn't really help you very much ;). The basic usage however, is as a delegate to your `AppRouter` to implement the concrete logic which happens on route changes.

Comment: Nice, thx for the explanation, it helped a lot. I'm particularly interested in the Controllers because I have a situation that, right after the user logs in, he have 2 different site areas where he can do totally different things. As long as I'm using AMD, resource management is a must here - I don't want requirejs to include the files from both areas into the html head. If I have a Controller, I can check the user permissions and redirect to the area he is allowed to enter. But I don't know if the Controller was made to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: I think what you describe is a perfect use case for the controller. The router would delegate the handling of that route to a method on the controller which could serve up a different view, or perhaps redirect to another route, based on your permissions logic.